# What are the best settings on Android and iOS devices to guarantee the best level of delivery for FCM push notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'd like to know what settings I should advise my end users to apply on their devices to get the best chance of having the push notifications delivered?

Comment: On iOS users will have to give the notification permission.On Android some devices have a whitelist of apps that are allowed to receive messages in the background, users should add your app if that is the case with their device.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.